# Jquery selector finding input inside fieldset

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I like to find value of an input box which is inside a fieldset as follows

```
fieldset> div >div> input[with class name 'inputclassname']
```

I know the id of fieldset and trying to find value of input with its class name but I am not able to .value is undefined.

I tried like this

```
$('#ID of fieldset').find($('.inputclassname')).val();
```

it always returning as undefined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<fieldset id="fs">
    <div>
        <div> 
            <input class="someclass" value="hey" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    alert($("#fs input.someclass").val())
</script>
```

Comment: Find is the preferred way in this case actually. This way the performance benefits of direct id selector are offset because you are trying to do a descendant selection. It is better to first select by the ID and then do a find as @Mohammed ElSayed has already shown

Answer (score 4):

try this (find need another selector, not a jquery object):

```
$('#ID of fieldset').find('.inputclassname').each(function(){
    var value = jQuery(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Noting that you don't need `.each()` if you just want the value of the first match (or are confident there will be only one match).

Answer (score 2):

this should fix your problem

```
$('#ID of fieldset').find('.inputclassname').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/pSS2v/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('#IDoffieldset input[class="inputclassname"]').val();
```

or

```
$('#IDoffieldset .inputclassname').val();
```

No need for `find()`. This uses the [descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and the [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selectors

Update from comments : But as you can see here [jsperf tests](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector/14) using find() is faster !! so  your best method is indeed :

```
 $('#IDoffieldset').find('input.inputclassname').val();
```

Comment: Find is the preferred way in this case actually. This way the performance benefits of direct id selector are offset because you are trying to do a descendant selection. It is better to first select by the ID and then do a find as @silly has already shown

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have never seen somebody use `input[class="inputclassname"]` before. Why would you do that when you can say `input.inputclassname`? (To answer my own question, perhaps if and only if you want to be sure the element has no other classes specified?)

Comment: @labroo thanks for pointing that out your are indeed correct (http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector/14)