# jQuery find ID in a fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a an ID of a `select` element inside a `fieldset`, I have tried

```
$('#fieldsetID select #idOfSelect');
```

And

```
$('#fieldsetID).find('select #idOfSelect');
```

Both appear as undefined in the JS console.

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: as mentioned by @Bhojendra - omit the spaces. they put the `idOfSelect` in context as a child of `select`

Comment: It seems to be duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615777/jquery-selector-finding-input-inside-fieldset

Comment: are you trying to find ID of select element or select element from its id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put space between select and it's id as it is the id of select not the children id of the select:

```
$('#fieldsetID select#idOfSelect');
```

Or,

```
$('#fieldsetID').find('select#idOfSelect');
```

Comment: `id` should be unique. Wouldn't this waste time, my understanding is that jquery search's are 'right to left' so it would find the `idOfSelect` then travel up to confirm its a select inside an element of id `fieldsetID`?

Comment: what if you are in the $('#fieldsetID') and from there you want to find the id??? So, I didn't posted as your ans since OP is wanting to find the element...

Comment: Its still slower to prefix it with a parent then use find, [see this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/right-to-left-jquery)

Comment: The answer is not only about using or finding an id, in the case later if OP want to find some class then your answer would be invalid in such case this answer provides better understanding for his work... we should be just relevant to the OP.....

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. In my mind not pointing out that id's should be unique doesn't better the OP's understanding

Comment: Since you also provided the answer informing unique id, I didn't  give an effort to that in my answer. So both answer helps to the OP. But it's really not about unique id from the question wanting to find element and what did the mistake and how should have done that is solution...

Comment: And why are we discussing such things long ... may be OP know about id is unique...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't prefix the `id` as the id attribute should be unique.
Just make sure the dom has loaded and you should be fine with:

```
$(function () {
    var myElement = $('#idOfSelect'); // should get the element you need
    console.log(myElement); // should show it in the console
});
```

You should only use the `id` of the element in the search and not prefix it with other elements. CSS selectors search '[right to left](http://davidwalsh.name/selectors)' so prefixing it when you are searching for an `id` serves no purpose.

Here is a [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/right-to-left-jquery) to show that prefixing with an `id` of a parent is slower.